# C program: converting an if statement code to a code which does not use logical, relational operators or selection construct (NO switch allowed)

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement, logical-operators

I have this piece of code written down in C. It's fairly simple and straightforward to understand. How do I convert the if-statement towards the end of the program into a statement that doesn't use any kind of logical or relational operator, any selection constructs, or any array? This means that the if statement has to be converted to a simple arithmetic piece of code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main (void)
{
    //Declarations

    int m;  //mass of the object
    int vi; //initial velocity of the object
    int ur; //coefficient of resistance
    int choice; //choice
    double net_force; //net force acting on the object
    double force_grav; //force due to gravity only
    double force_res; //force due to the resistance only
    double force_des; //Desired force in output section

    #define g 9.8

    //Input statements
    printf("Please input the mass in kilograms:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Please input the launch speed (m/s):");
    scanf("%d",&vi);
    printf("Please input the coefficient of resistance (kg/s):");
    scanf("%d",&ur);

    //Executable Statements
    printf("Choices for calculation:\n");
    printf("1. Force due to gravity only\n");
    printf("2. Net force\n");
    printf("3. Force due to resistance only\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    //Calculations
    force_grav = m * g;
    force_res = (-1) * ur * vi;
    net_force = force_res + force_grav;


    if(choice==1)
        printf("Desired force: %2.3lf", force_grav);
    else
        if(choice==2)
            printf("Desired force: %2.3lf", net_force);
        else
            printf("Desired force: %2.3lf", force_res);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: @ChunkwinJoe: Something like `const double g = 9.8;` would be a much better idea.

Comment: It's much safer to use `if () {... } else if { ... } else { ... }` to make sure that changes to the code do not effect flow of control. K&R C talks about how C syntax using braces or no braces effects flow of control in the code.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with "relational algebra", which involves operators on relations/tables used for databases. (Google/wiki it.)

Comment: What does your assignment/exercise say, *exactly*?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion if the problem shall be tackled *arithmetically* is:

```
force_grav = m * g;
force_res = (-1) * ur * vi;
net_force = force_res + force_grav;

force = force_grav*(2-choice)*(3-choice)/2 + 
        force_res*(1-choice)*(2-choice)/2  +
        net_force*(1-choice)*(3-choice)*(-1);

printf("Desired force: %2.3lf", force);
```

The variable "choice" effectively chooses now, which summands contribute to the result of the term.

The term can of course be simplified, but I let it "as is" to show the concept.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful (other than to blindly cut and paste) unless you explain the concept. "As is", it does not "show the concept", it shows the  result of applying the concept.

Comment: @ChunkwinJoe Thanks are discouraged, but please consider upvoting helpful answers (arrow icon) (when you have enough rep) and/or accepting a best one (check mark icon).

Answer (score 1):

This my first attempt

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main (void)
{
    //Declarations

    int m;  //mass of the object
    int vi; //initial velocity of the object
    int ur; //coefficient of resistance
    int choice; //choice
    double force_grav; //force due to gravity only
    double force_res; //force due to the resistance only

    const double g = 9.8;

    //Input statements
    printf("Please input the mass in kilograms:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Please input the launch speed (m/s):");
    scanf("%d",&vi);
    printf("Please input the coefficient of resistance (kg/s):");
    scanf("%d",&ur);

    //Executable Statements
    printf("Choices for calculation:\n");
    printf("1. Force due to gravity only\n");
    printf("2. Net force\n");
    printf("3. Force due to resistance only\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    //Calculations
    force_grav = m * g;
    force_res = (-1) * ur * vi;

    printf("Desired force: %2.3lf\n", ((force_res*((choice&2)>>1)) + (force_grav*(choice&1))));
}
```

Another can be

```
printf("Desired force: %2.3lf\n", ((force_res*(choice/2)) + (force_grav*(choice%2))));
```

**Little explanation:**

**In the first example** you can use bit set by choice to "allow a value to summed for the output:

- `0x01` only bit 0 set
- `0x02` only bit 1 set
- `0x03` both bit 0 and 2 set

**In the second example** you can use modulo and integer division to allow value to be summed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple but unsafe way to do it. Note there is no check on the value/choice entered, but checking would require an if......

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main (void)
{
    //Declarations

    int m;  //mass of the object
    int vi; //initial velocity of the object
    int ur; //coefficient of resistance
    int choice; //choice
    double net_force; //net force acting on the object
    //double force_grav; //force due to gravity only
    //double force_res; //force due to the resistance only
    //double force_des; //Desired force in output section
    double forces[3];

    #define g 9.8

    //Input statements
    printf("Please input the mass in kilograms:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Please input the launch speed (m/s):");
    scanf("%d",&vi);
    printf("Please input the coefficient of resistance (kg/s):");
    scanf("%d",&ur);

    //Executable Statements
    printf("Choices for calculation:\n");
    printf("1. Force due to gravity only\n");
    printf("2. Net force\n");
    printf("3. Force due to resistance only\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    //Calculations
    forces[0] = m * g;                   // force_grav
    forces[2] = (-1) * ur * vi;          // force_res
    forces[1] = forces[0] + forces[2];  // net_force

#if 0
    if(choice==1)
        printf("Desired force: %2.3lf", force_grav);
    else
        if(choice==2)
            printf("Desired force: %2.3lf", net_force);
        else
            printf("Desired force: %2.3lf", force_res);
#endif

   // CAUTION: SHOULD HAVE A CHECK ON THE VALUE OF CHOICE
   // E.G. if (choice > 0 && choice < 4)
   // BUT THAT'D REQUIRE AN IF......

   printf("Desired force: %2.3lf\n", forces[choice-1]);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: As commented by OP, arrays are not allowed.